# Matlab: Write Image Sequences into a Folder

Tags: image, matlab, file-io

I am trying to write a sequence of images into a folder using `imwrite` function in Matlab. I first crop the input image (`inputImg`) with a given matrix as `cropMatrix`, then save those resulted images in order to a folder. My code for it is as follows:

```
for i = 1:n
    img = imcrop(inputImg,cropMatrix);
    fileName = sprintf('C:\Users\King_Knight\Desktop\Images\%02d',i);
    imwrite ( img, 'fileName', 'jpg');
end
```

Then the folder is totally empty, it didn't write out anything, besides I got a warning message in the Matlab workspace saying:

```
Warning: Escape sequence '\U' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape sequences.
```

I've searched the internet, but still couldn't solve it. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*printf` set of functions in Matlab will interpret C-style escape codes, which always start with the character `\`.  A common problem is of course that Windows uses the backslash as a directory separator.

The simple solution is the escape all of the backslashes using `\\`.  For example:

```
fileName = sprintf('C:\\Users\\King_Knight\\Desktop\\Images\\%02d',i);
```

will actually create the string `C:\Users\King_Knight\Desktop\Images\00`, as required.

You can read the relevant documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0hr54).

Note that in Matlab, unlike C, this only applies to the functions `fprintf`, `sprintf` etc.  You **don't** have to do it for other functions such as `disp`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it, then the warning message has gone, but the folder is still empty. It didn't write out anything. I used 'imshow' to see whether 'img' is an empty image or not, but it diplayed it correctly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.  Does the folder you want to write to exist?

Comment: I tried 'imwrite(img,'C:\\Users\\King_Knight\\Desktop\\Images\\test.jpg')', and it wrote out this one to me in the folder.

Comment: Ok, I think I've solved it. I saved the working dir using 'dir=pwd', then in the 'for' loop, before 'imwrite', I used 'cd('C:\\Users\\King_Knight\\Desktop\\Images\\'), and after 'imwrite', I used 'cd(dir)' to go back to the original folder. Now it writes images correctly.

Comment: Bear in mind the final point I made: you **only** have to use the escaped backslash (`\\`) for `sprintf` and `fprintf`, not for other strings.

Comment: Don't manually escape paths passed to `sprintf` and `fprintf`. You're asking for trouble. Pass them as strings: `path='C:\Users\King_Knight\Desktop\Images\';` `fileName=sprintf('%s%02d',path,i);` and they'll be escaped automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
clear all;
%%%% Image Read
%%

input_folder  = '..'; %  Enter name of folder from which you want to upload pictures with full path
output_folder = '..';
filenames = dir(fullfile(input_folder, '*.jpg'));  % read all images with specified extention, its jpg in our case
total_images = numel(filenames);    % count total number of photos present in that folder
Outputs=total_images;
dir=output_folder;

%%

%%
for i = 1:total_images
    full_name= fullfile(input_folder, filenames(i).name);     % it will specify images names with full path and extension
    our_images = imread(full_name);                           % Read images  
    figure (i);                                               % used tat index n so old figures are not over written by new new figures
    imshow(our_images);                                       % Show all images 
    I = our_images;
    I = imresize(I, [384  384]);   

   filename = [sprintf('%03d',i) '.jpg'];
   fullname = fullfile(output_folder,'output_folder',filename);
   imwrite(I,fullname)    % Write out to a JPEG file (img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc.)


end

%%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the image into destination folder use the following code in MATLAB.

```
destinationFolder = 'C:\Users\Deepa\Desktop\imagefolder'; % Your folder path
if ~exist(destinationFolder, 'dir')
  mkdir(destinationFolder);
end
baseFileName = sprintf('%d.png', i); % e.g. "1.png"
fullFileName = fullfile(destinationFolder, baseFileName); 
imwrite(img, fullFileName); % img respresents input image.
```

I hope this answer might help someone.